# Create URL with JSON object as header

Tags: json, url, get

I'm exploring Bitso API (Bitso is a mexican crypto exchange).

The docs of the API is well explained at some languages such as Python and Ruby for its use. The problem here is that there are no examples using straight URLs for request.

What I'm planning to do is to create the URL that the code is creating on its requests function.

There is a request for balance account, that is the data I'd like to get. 
According documentation, this is a private request that need some headers at the request (Key, nonce and signature), you can take a look [here](https://bitso.com/api_info?shell#creating-and-signing-requests).

The code to make this request in Python is the following one:

```
import time
import hmac
import hashlib
import requests

bitso_key = "BITSO_KEY"
bitso_secret = "BITSO_SECRET"
nonce =  str(int(round(time.time() * 1000)))
http_method = "GET"
request_path = "/v3/balance/"
json_payload = ""

# Create signature
message = nonce+http_method+request_path+json_payload
signature = hmac.new(bitso_secret.encode('utf-8'),
                                            message.encode('utf-8'),
                                            hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

# Build the auth header
auth_header = 'Bitso %s:%s:%s' % (bitso_key, nonce, signature)

# Send request
response = requests.get("https://api.bitso.com/v3/balance/", headers={"Authorization": auth_header})

print(response.content)
```

So based in this I could say that the URL is something like this:

```
https://api.bitso.com/v3/balance/Bitso%20<Key>:<nonce>:<signature>
```

I'm sure that I'm wrong with that supposition, I understand that `headers={"Authorization": auth_header}` seems to be a JSON object used as header in the URL, but I'd like to know how that JSON object is translated at the URL to make a request. I'd like to copy-paste that URL at the browser and get the data as response.

I need that URL so I could use it to connect the service to a Business Intelligence tool.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation this **Authorization** is a header in the request. You can try using postman but you still need hash the destination URL with your api key and the nonce to avoid replay attacks.